# In async.until(test, function, callback) test function is not getting invoked repetitively

Tags: javascript, callback, async.js

While I was using async.until() function I observed that the test is not getting invoked repetitively though it is returning false. As a result function is not getting invoked to perform the next task.

```
var resultReceived = false;
async.until(function(){
    console.log("Checking result : "+resultReceived);
            return resultReceived;
}, function(callback){
   try{
       //do something
       resultReceived = true;
   }catch(err){
       resultReceived = false;
   }
}, function(result){
            console.log("====================");
            console.log(result);
            callback(result);
});
```

Comment: Yes - this is because asynchronous means that it doesn't wait for the previous execution to complete before starting the next -- see this answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/748175/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-execution-what-does-it-really-mean

Comment: Yes I understand. but If you check this documentation [https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#until] it says it repeatedly call main function until test returns true. That's why I was wondering..

Answer (score 1):

The reason you only see the test function invoked once is because you never advance past the first iteration. In order to move from one iteration to the next, you need to invoke `callback` in the second function that you pass to `async.until`.

Here is a slightly modified example that will show the test function being invoked with each iteration:

```
var iteration = 0;
async.until(function(){
    console.log("Checking iteration : " + iteration);
    return iteration > 5;
}, function(callback){
  console.log(++iteration);
  setTimeout(callback, 1000);
}, function(result){
    console.log("====================");
    console.log(result);
});
```